# Assigning values to extended User model in Django

Tags: django

I have the code like so. The post save creates a row in the table, but how do I assign values to `socialid` and `accesstoken`?

```
class Appuser(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
socialid = models.IntegerField(null=True)
accesstoken = models.CharField(max_length=255L, null = True)
class Meta:
    db_table = 'AppUser'
def __str__(self):  
      return "%s's profile" % self.user  

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_cfituser(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):  
    if created:  
        Appuser.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

Running this in the shell is giving me:

```
>>> user = User.objects.create_user('John Doe')
>>> appuser = Appuser(user = user,accesstoken = '634646473', socialid='6436') 
>>> appuser.save()
"Duplicate entry '9' for key 'user_id'"
```

which makes sense because that row already exists. It's probably something simple that I'm missing so any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Django 1.5

Comment: Please read [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user) of the documentation, especially [the full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example). Once you have gone through that, it should help clarify your problem.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Just a clarification, so you mean to say that just extending the OneToOne field isn't sufficient and I have to create a custom User Model like so `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'`?

Comment: Yes; and in doing so it will provide you all the flexibilty and you won't have to bother with signals (which are really a great way to introduce "mysterious features" (ie, bugs) in your code).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid `Changing AUTH_USER_MODEL has a big effect on your database structure. It changes the tables that are available, and it will affect the construction of foreign keys and many-to-many relationships.` Would you say that despite this it is better than using signals?

Comment: Yes, despite all that.

Comment: Check your AUTH_USER database sequence, which determines what the next id should be (in your database administration section). This may be named AUTH_USER_SQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a separate model with a OneToOne is no longer recommended, since you can extend the User model directly instead. That said, what's wrong here is that your signal is creating the Appuser, but then you try and create another one. Instead, get the one that was created by the signal:

```
user = User.objects.create_user('John Doe')
appuser = Appuser.objects.get(user=user)
appuser.accesstoken = '634646473'
appuser.socialid = 6436
appuser.save()
```

Note that normally you can get from `user` to `appuser` by just doing `user.appuser`, but this probably won't work at this point because the appuser didn't exist at the time you got the User. The next time you get either the Appuser or the User from the db, the direct reference will work.

Comment: First off, this worked perfectly, thank you. Could you please elaborate on extending the User model? [These](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) are the methods available correct? Which do you suggest?

Comment: Well, I was referring to the "substituting a custom user model" a bit further down the page. Although the bit you've linked to does imply that the separate profile model, which you've used, is not un-recommended, even if it isn't actually recommended.